# Placing a third subfigure at the center in latex

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to figure out how to place three images in a triangular order in latex.

[image]

Subfigure 3 is not aligned at the center.

I have the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Images/5_Res/bloodstream1.png}
  \caption{Case 1}
  \label{fig:BC}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Images/5_Res/bloodstream2.png}
  \caption{Case 2}
  \label{fig:DC}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Images/5_Res/bloodstream3.png}
  \caption{Case 3}
  \label{fig:EC}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Different types of blood vessels}
\label{comparison-blood-vessels}
\end{figure}
```

I tried removing the `\centering` in the subfigure 3 but could not achieve it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write your figure code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering   %
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{Images/5_Res/bloodstream1.png}
  \caption{Case 1}
  \label{fig:BC}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{Images/5_Res/bloodstream2.png}
  \caption{Case 2}
  \label{fig:DC}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{Images/5_Res/bloodstream3.png}
  \caption{Case 3}
  \label{fig:EC}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Different types of blood vessels}
\label{comparison-blood-vessels}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A you can see to your code fragment are added:

- keys `Gin` for shorter code
- after `\begin{figure} command` \centering`
- between first and second row with images is empty line
- width of `subfigure` is reduced to desired width of images. Consequently all `\centering in` subfigure` are (can be) omitted

[image]